# Sealed trait and dynamic case objects

Tags: scala

I have a few enumerations implemented as sealed traits and case objects. I prefer using the ADT approach because of the non-exhaustive warnings and mostly because we want to avoid the type erasure. Something like this

```
 sealed abstract class Maker(val value: String) extends Product with Serializable {
    override def toString = value
  }

  object Maker {
    case object ChryslerMaker extends Vendor("Chrysler")
    case object ToyotaMaker extends Vendor("Toyota")
    case object NissanMaker extends Vendor("Nissan")
    case object GMMaker extends Vendor("General Motors")
    case object UnknownMaker extends Vendor("")

    val tipos = List(ChryslerMaker, ToyotaMaker, NissanMaker,GMMaker, UnknownMaker)
    private val fromStringMap: Map[String, Maker] = tipos.map(s => s.toString -> s).toMap

    def apply(key: String): Option[Maker] = fromStringMap.get(key)
  }
```

This is working well so far, now we are considering providing access to other programmers to our code to allow them to configure on site. I see two potential problems:
1) People messing up and writing things like:

```
case object ChryslerMaker extends Vendor("Nissan")
```

and people forgetting to update the tipos

I have been looking into using a configuration file (JSON or csv) to provide these values and read them as we do with plenty of other elements, but all the answers I have found rely on macros and seem to be extremely dependent on the scala version used (2.12 for us).

What I would like to find is:
1a) (Prefered) a way to create dynamically the case objects from a list of strings making sure the objects are named consistently with the value they hold
1b) (Acceptable) if this proves too hard a way to obtain the objects and the values during the test phase
2) Check that the number of elements in the list matches the number of case objects created.

I forgot to mention, I have looked briefly to enumeratum but I would prefer not to include additional libraries unless i really understand the pros and cons (and right now I am not sure how enumerated compares with the ADT approach, if you think this is the best way and can point me to such discussion that would work great)

Thanks !

Comment: I don't get why you don't want to just use `Enumeration` it has things you are describing straight out of the box ...

Comment: @Dima, maybe they have now and I missed that... here is a reference (there are plenty) https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html

Comment: @Luis Miguel... I had no idea SBT could do that, i guess I should read some sbt book. Yes I am definitely interested, I really like that approach. Now that i know this I may even use in other parts of the code. It seems sbt is the new emacs :)

Comment: no need for references, I know how to use enumerations :) 
If you have specific questions or problems, ask away ...

Comment: @Dima Am I wrong that Enumerations do not provide the non-exhaustive pattern matching and do perform type erasure? I have been using ADTs because of this for the last 3 years and that was the situation, maybe I missed something.

Comment: No, you are not wrong. Type erasure is really a non-issue (overloading methods is not a good practice, and there are tricks around the type erasure if you have to do that anyway). As for the non-exhaustive warnings, I submit that a missing warning in one case is a smaller issue than having to run external commands/build the whole project before you can even begin writing the match ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea that comes to my mind is to create an [**SBT** `SourceGenerator` *task*](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html).
That will read an input JSON, CSV, XML or whatever file, that is part of your project and will create a scala file.

```
// ----- File: project/VendorsGenerator.scala -----
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

/**
 * An SBT task that generates a managed source file with all Scalastyle inspections.
 */
object VendorsGenerator {
  // For demonstration, I will use this plain List[String] to generate the code,
  // you may change the code to read a file instead.
  // Or maybe this will be good enough.
  final val vendors: List[String] =
    List(
      "Chrysler",
      "Toyota",
      ...
      "Unknow"
    )

  val generatorTask = Def.task {
    // Make the 'tipos' List, which contains all vendors.
    val tipos =
      vendors
        .map(vendorName => s"${vendorName}Vendor")
        .mkString("val tipos: List[Vendor] = List(", ",", ")")

    // Make a case object for each vendor.
    val vendorObjects = vendors.map { vendorName =>
      s"""case object ${vendorName}Vendor extends Vendor { override final val value: String = "${vendorName}" }"""
    }

    // Fill the code template.
    val code =
      List(
        List(
          "package vendors",
          "sealed trait Vendor extends Product with Serializable {",
          "def value: String",
          "override final def toString: String = value",
          "}",
          "object Vendors extends (String => Option[Vendor]) {"
        ),
        vendorObjects,
        List(
          tipos,
          "private final val fromStringMap: Map[String, Vendor] = tipos.map(v => v.toString -> v).toMap",
          "override def apply(key: String): Option[Vendor] = fromStringMap.get(key.toLowerCase)",
          "}"
        )
      ).flatten

    // Save the new file to the managed sources dir.
    val vendorsFile = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "vendors.scala"
    IO.writeLines(vendorsFile, code)
    Seq(vendorsFile)
  }
}
```

Now, you can activate your source generator.
This task will be run each time, before the compile step.

```
// ----- File: build.sbt -----
sourceGenerators in Compile += VendorsGenerator.generatorTask.taskValue
```

**Please note that I suggest this, because I have done it before and because I don't have any macros nor meta programming experience.**
**Also, note that this example relays a lot in Strings, which make the code a little bit hard to understand and maintain.**

BTW, I haven't used `enumeratum`, but giving it a quick look looks like the best solution to this problem

### Edit

> I have my code ready to read a HOCON file and generate the matching code. My question now is where to place the scala file in the project directory and where will the files be generated. I am a little bit confused because there seems to be multiple steps 1) compile my scala generator, 2) run the generator, and 3) compile and build the project. Is this right?

Your generator is not part of your project code, but instead of your meta-project *(I know that sounds confusing, you may read [this](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html) for understanding that)* - as such, you place the generator inside the `project` folder at the root level *(the same folder where is the `build.properties` file for specifying the **sbt version**)*.
If your generator needs some dependencies *(I'm sure it does for reading the **HOCON**)* you place them in a `build.sbt` file inside that `project` folder.
If you plan to add unit test to the generator, you may create an entire scala project inside the meta-project *(you may give a look to the [`project` **folder**](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala/tree/master/project) of a open source project (Yes, yes I know, confusing again) in which I work for reference)* - My personal suggestion is that more than testing the generator itself, you should test the generated file instead, or better both.

The generated file will be automatically placed in the `src_managed` folder *(which lives inside `target` and thus it is ignored from your source code version control)*.
The path inside that is just by *order*, as everything inside the `src_managed` folder is included by default when compiling.

```
val vendorsFile = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "vendors.scala" // Path to the file to write.`
```

In order to access the values defined in the generated file on your source code, you only need to add a package to the generated file and import the values from that package in your code *(as with any normal file)*.

You don't need to worry about anything related with compilation order, if you include your source generator in your `build.sbt` file, **SBT** will take care of everything automatically.

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += VendorsGenerator.generatorTask.taskValue // Activate the source generator.
```

**SBT** will re-run your generator everytime it needs to compile.

> "BTW I get "not found: object sbt" on the imports".

If the project is inside the meta-project space, it will find the sbt package by default, don't worry about it.

Comment: This is a great idea precisely because you have done it before (and it works) and I have no intention to go down the scala macros rabbit hole! Regarding enumeratum i fail to see how to programmatically create the objects, same situation i have now.

Comment: I have my code ready to read a HOCON file and generate the matching code. My question now is where to place the scala file in the project directory and where will the files be generated. I am a little bit confused because there seems to be multiple steps 1) compile my scala generator, 2) run the generator, and 3) compile and build the project. Is this right?

Comment: BTW I get "not found: object sbt" on the imports.

Comment: @LuisSisamon I updated the answer, hope it helps. Let me know when you see it to delete this comment. If you have further problems don't doubt to ask, but I think it will be better to made it in chat instead.

Comment: Getting closer but not yet. You are probably right chat will work better, in the meantime I created a GitHub repository https://github.com/sisamon/generator

Comment: @LuisSisamon I solved your problems! :D - I invited you to a chat for giving you a detailed explanation.