# How to model an enum of String based static Ids in Scala?

Tags: scala, orm, enumeration, jooq

let's say I have a reference data table `roles` filled with all roles that a user might be granted. The rows are quite stable, meaning that it's uncommon that someone adds a new role to the table. Additionally there's a `users` table and a join-table `users_roles`. In fact, the `roles` table is just required to grant a user some predefined roles by adding a record to `users_roles`.

The `roles` table is quite simple:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin.roles (
  id          CHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
  description VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
```

The following example describes a role:

```sql
INSERT INTO admin.roles VALUES('CS_AGENT', 'A customer service agent');
```

Obviously, I need the possible `id` values somewhere in my code. This is a set of Strings, but I'd like to prevent magic Strings and make this more type safe.

As far as I understand, there are several options:

- create a symbol for each role id
- create a new type `RoleId` that extends `String` and declare vals

In order to define the set of role ids, these are my options:

- use an `Enumeration`
- use a sealed trait/sealed object and derive case objects from it

I'm using JOOQ for my persistence layer, and it would be nice if I could use the type safe RoleId in my queries without manually converting it to String and vice versa.

What would be the best solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure I get all of your problem, but would not something like this be the solution?

```
/** Represents a RoleId from the roles table. */
sealed trait RoleId {
  def name: String
  def description: String
  override final def toString: String = name
}

object RoleId {
  case object CS_AGENT extends RoleId {
    override val name = "CS_AGENT"
    override val description = "A customer service agent"
  }
  // Define all other roles...

  /** All roles */
  val allRoles: Set[RoleId] = Set(
    CS_AGENT,
    // All other roles...
  )

  /** Returns an RoleId given its name, if the name is not found this will return a None. */
  def fromString(name: String): Option[RoleId] = name.toUpperCase match {
    case "CS_AGENT" => Some(CS_AGENT)
    // All other cases..
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

This is completely **typesafe** and if you need to go to/from a String there are the `toString` and `fromString` methods.

The only *(big)* downside of this approach is a lot of boilerplate code which is easy to screw up - creating a new `RoleId` but not adding it to the `Set`, typo in the name or in the case, etc.
An alternative to fixing this is to make this file autogenerated by **SBT** from some kind of config *(even reading the SQL table if reachable in the build environment)*, for that part [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926031/sealed-trait-and-dynamic-case-objects/53927349#53927349) of mine to another question may help.